# Airflow Add Google Cloud Connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I'm finding the documentation here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html
to be about as clear as mud and would be very grateful for some clarifications, please.

I am simply trying to create a connection to my gcp project from my airflow (running out of docker locally). I have a keyfile generated from a suitable service account, but don't know where I should put it.

[image]

What is the 'Keyfile path' relative to? Is that from the airflow webserver or the scheduler? Also the documentation suggests that the 'Keyfile JSON' takes the content of the keyfile, but whatever I try I still just get 'bad request' when I try to test the connection.

I am putting the project id in the appropriate field - the screen snip just doesn't show that.

Can anyone clarify, please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Keyfile JSON should the content of your Service_account .json file. Usually in the form of:

```
{"private_key": "r4nd0m_k3y"}
```

The Keyfile PATH should always be absolute - you just have to make sure it is available for the "workers" (or "scheduler" in case of Local executor - so basically for the entity that executes tasks). In Airflow 2.2 there is also a feature to "test" connections from the UI - if you want to use it, you will have to make it available under this path for Webserver.

Your `bad request` might come for a different reason BTW. - for example you might have to specify `scopes` - but you will need to debug it and make sure you have all configurations right. You can test it by providing the key via absolute path if unsure.

Finally - kind request when you get it working, i'd appreciate if you improve the documentation and add those working examples and explanation to make it clearer. It is super simple - go to the docs page and there is the "Suggest a change to this page" button which will open directly a PR and you wil be able to update the docs using GitHub UI. Very simple and straightforward and nice way not only to thank those who make the software available for free - but you can also become one of the more than 1700 contributors to Airflow and "clear the path" for others who had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried placing the key in absolute path on shared volume on each node, still no good. I tried pasting the key content into the keyfile json field (which gets obfuscated) still no good. I tried supplying basic scopes... still nothing. When I save the connection the fields have returned to default. Very strange.

Comment: Hard to say. You can try to define the connections via CLI or even environment variable (you have all the explanations and tools here and following chapters: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#creating-a-connection-from-the-cli - if after saving the connection the changes disapear, then you have probably another problem than key.  You can always inspect the metadata db of airflow to check if connection is properly defined or use `airflow connection` CLI to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the 'Keyfile path' relative to?**

> Copy the service account JSON key file that you downloaded into the
> data/ directory of your environment's Cloud Storage bucket. Then, in
> Keyfile Path, enter the local file path on the Airflow worker to the
> JSON keyfile's location, such as /home/airflow/gcs/data/keyfile.json.
> [Link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_a_connection_to_another_project)

**Is that from the airflow webserver or the scheduler?**

I'm not sure enough about the second question, but this configuration is made in the airflow webserver.

Consider reviewing the complete tutorial on [Managing Airflow Connections](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections). This might be useful with your connection issue.

Regarding the message **“Bad request”** you can review [this document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/core_errors#BAD_REQUEST) about Error messages in GCP.